# Powershell command-line with Autologon.exe

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Has anyone made the 'Autologon.exe for Windows v3.10' work with PowerShell v5.1?

**Execution 1:**

As administrator the following is run:

```
.\Autologon.exe -n guest10 -d test.com -p Password1 -accepteula yes
```

**Error 1:**

[image]

---

**Execution 2:**

As administrator in powershell the following is run:

```
.\Autologon.exe guest10 test.com Password1
```

**Error2:** Nothing happens

---

**Execution 3:**

As administrator in powershell the following is run:

```
$obj=.\Autologon.exe
        $name ="guest10"
        $domain="test"
        $pass="Password1"
        & $obj $name $domain $pass
```

**Error3:**

> The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.

Comment: What is `autologon.exe`? Also, `$name` would resolve to a PowerShell variable. If it is not defined, it is null.

Comment: Autologon is used to encrypt the values in the registry. Can be downloaded @ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon.aspx                       I define the variables before running them ex: $name="test" so it should not give a null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generally use `Start-Process` with the `ArgumentList` parameter to run programs with arguments:

```
$autologon = "C:\folder\Autologon.exe"
$username = "guest10"
$domain = "domain"
$password = "Password1"

Start-Process $autologon -ArgumentList $username,$domain,$password
```

Or you can put them directly into the command:

```
Start-Process "C:\folder\Autologon.exe" -ArgumentList "guest10","domain","Password1"
```

Comment: It looks to be a slash not dash so try `/accepteula`

Comment: Verified that this works:Start-Process "C:\folder\Autologon.exe" -ArgumentList "guest10","domain","Password1","/accepteula"

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

`Start-Process -FilePath  $exePath -ArgumentList "/accepteula", $user, $domain, $password -Wait`

It's very picky about quote placement.

Answer (score 0):

As Stephan mentioned, however without args, here's how I did it and it worked perfectly.

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\Autologon.exe" -ArgumentList '"/accepteula" username domain password'
```